# apply function for a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I wrote a function that split my data frame to 7 Different data frames. so far everything OK. but I'm trying to apply this function on a list of dataframes

this is the list I made:

```
m  =list(X2016_kvish_1_10t, X2015_kvish_1_10t, X2014_kvish_1_10t,
         X2013_kvish_1_10t, X2012_kvish_1_10t, X2011_kvish_1_10t,
         X2010_kvish_1_10t, X2009_kvish_1_10t, X2008_kvish_1_10t,
         X2007_kvish_1_10t, X2006_kvish_1_10t, X2005_kvish_1_10t)
```

and this is the function to the first dataframe (single dataframe):

```
 y = c(X2016_kvish_1_10t$nefah) # add the average traffic volume values per each day in the week (1-7)
n = 24
my.split <- function(y, n) split(y, sort(rep(letters[1:n], each=n, len=length(y)))) #function to split the Traffic volume values to 7 groups 
splitted_values = my.split(y, n)
mean_values.1_10t_2016 = lapply(splitted_values, mean) # Find the average traffic volume values for each day
mean_values.1_10t_2016 = rep(mean_values.1_10t_2016, each = 24) # Multiply the number of times the traffic volume values are displayed to fit the table
```

so far it works OK. but I need to apply this function for all the 12 dataframes
so instead of define y as:

```
y = c(X2016_kvish_1_10t$nefah)
```

I would like do define y as:

```
y = c(m$nefah) # same column in each dataframe
```

but when I do this way It doesn't work. please help me

the dataframes look like this:

```
> X2016_kvish_1_10t
kvish keta maslul yom nefah status                date
1       1   10      1   1  1710     NA 2016-09-11 00:00:00
2       1   10      1   1   934     NA 2016-09-11 01:00:00
3       1   10      1   1   800     NA 2016-09-11 02:00:00
4       1   10      1   1   637     NA 2016-09-11 03:00:00
5       1   10      1   1   588     NA 2016-09-11 04:00:00
6       1   10      1   1   951     NA 2016-09-11 05:00:00
7       1   10      1   1  2312     NA 2016-09-11 06:00:00
8       1   10      1   1  3769     NA 2016-09-11 07:00:00
9       1   10      1   1  3348     NA 2016-09-11 08:00:00
#168 rows in total
```

the structure of m :

```
> str(m)
List of 12
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 1710 934 800 637 588 951 2312 3769 3348 2788 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2016-09-11 00:00:00" "2016-09-11 01:00:00" "2016-09-11 02:00:00" "2016-09-11 03:00:00" ...
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 ..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ yom   : int [1:168] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 ..$ nefah : int [1:168] 1346 788 626 652 597 798 2344 3617 3669 2873 ...
 ..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2015-06-15 00:00:00" "2015-06-15 01:00:00" "2015-06-15 02:00:00" "2015-06-15 03:00:00" ...
 $ :'data.frame':   168 obs. of  7 variables:
 ..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 ..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ nefah : int [1:168] 1936 966 737 596 479 765 2082 3624 3847 2960 ...
 ..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2014-09-07 00:00:00" "2014-09-07 01:00:00" "2014-09-07 02:00:00" "2014-09-07 03:00:00" ...
  $ :'data.frame':  168 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 2066 1242 875 667 676 976 2630 4337 4282 3437 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2013-05-19 00:00:00" "2013-05-19 01:00:00" "2013-05-19 02:00:00" "2013-05-19 03:00:00" ...
 $ :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int(0) 
..$ keta  : int(0) 
..$ maslul: int(0) 
..$ yom   : int(0) 
..$ nefah : int(0) 
..$ status: int(0) 
..$ date  :Classes 'POSIXct', 'POSIXt'  atomic (0) 
..- attr(*, "tzone")= chr "UTC"
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 1454 1039 700 623 459 681 1971 3369 3513 2641 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2011-05-15 00:00:00" "2011-05-15 01:00:00" "2011-05-15 02:00:00" "2011-05-15 03:00:00" ...
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 1405 760 471 527 637 1278 4781 5902 5462 5297 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2010-05-09 00:00:00" "2010-05-09 01:00:00" "2010-05-09 02:00:00" "2010-05-09 03:00:00" ...
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 2123 1479 1327 946 743 966 2419 3893 3650 3300 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2009-10-11 00:00:00" "2009-10-11 01:00:00" "2009-10-11 02:00:00" "2009-10-11 03:00:00" ...
$ :'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7 variables:
..$ kvish : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : int [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : int [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : int [1:168] 2233 1439 1042 918 763 1024 2621 4348 4435 3742 ...
..$ status: int [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2008-05-04 00:00:00" "2008-05-04 01:00:00" "2008-05-04 02:00:00" "2008-05-04 03:00:00" ...
$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    168 obs. of  7   variables:
..$ kvish : atomic [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "kvish"
..$ keta  : atomic [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "keta"
..$ maslul: atomic [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "maslul"
..$ yom   : atomic [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "yom"
..$ nefah : atomic [1:168] 1791 1130 785 717 571 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "nefah"
..$ status: atomic [1:168] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
.. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "status"
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2007-01-21 00:00:00" "2007-01-21 01:00:00" "2007-01-21 02:00:00" "2007-01-21 03:00:00" ...
$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    168 obs. of  6 variables:
..$ kvish : num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : num [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : num [1:168] 2408 1539 1114 990 851 ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2006-09-03 00:00:00" "2006-09-03 01:00:00" "2006-09-03 02:00:00" "2006-09-03 03:00:00" ...
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   168 obs. of  6 variables:
..$ kvish : num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ keta  : num [1:168] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
..$ maslul: num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ yom   : num [1:168] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ nefah : num [1:168] 2743 1759 1227 1077 1019 ...
..$ date  : POSIXct[1:168], format: "2005-05-01 00:00:00" "2005-05-01 01:00:00" "2005-05-01 02:00:00" "2005-05-01 03:00:00" ...
```

> 

Comment: I'm really having a hard time trying to understand what you wanna do... `m` is a list of characters. And if you wanna set `y`as being `m$nefah` while `nefah`would be a column name, `m`should be a dataframe. There is no point in splitting a list... where is your dataframe that you want to split?

Comment: I defined m as al list of data frame. each data frame has the "nefah" column and for each data frame I would like to split it to 7 different parts as I did in the example

Answer (score 1):

Please check if it is somewhat close to what you want...

```
n = 24
my.split <- function(y, n) split(y, sort(rep(letters[1:n], each=n, len=length(y)))) #function to split the Traffic volume values to 7 groups 
splitted_values = lapply(m, function(x) my.split(x$nefah, n))
mean_values <- lapply(splitted_values, function(x) lapply(x, mean)) # Find the average traffic volume values for each day
mean_values <- lapply(mean_values, unlist) 
mean_values = lapply(mean_values, function(x) rep(x, each = 24))
```

Comment: I tried, and it shows me this error: Error in x$nefah : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Since I'm applying `my.split` to the elements of your list and it takes the column `nefah` from every element, the error is saying that your list's elements are not really data frames but vectors instead. Please provide a sample of your `m` list and of, at least, the `head` of two data frames from it.

Comment: my list elements are all data.frame type. I checked .

Comment: Could you provide at least the result of `str` of your list?

Comment: I made a list of three `mtcars` dataframes and I'm able to run the code up to the third line with no problems, works here.

Comment: In fact, I was able to run the entire code in this made up `mtcars` list.

Comment: I uploaded the str(m) of the list

Comment: Thanks, It works. now I need paste each part of the list for each original data.frame as a new column

Comment: I think this might do the trick: `for(i in 1:length(m)){m[[i]]$means <- mean_values[[i]]}`

Comment: I tried what you wrote now, but It didn't paste me new columns of the mean values

Comment: Strange, I got this code to run here with my made up `mtcars` list and it added the new column. I'll still review the code though.

Comment: its seem to work but not as a constant column. can you show me another way using mutate?

Comment: `for(i in 1:length(m)){
  m[[i]] <- mutate(m[[i]], means = mean_values[[i]])
}`

Comment: Its write me an error:  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Unsupported type NILSXP for column "means"

Comment: What is the result of `str(mean_values)`?

Comment: look: when I print `m[[I]]` It shows me this: `[1] kvish  keta   maslul yom    nefah  status date`. so I think it refers to the columns of each data.frame and not to the data.frames themselves

Comment: Does this happen to all `m[[i]]`?

Comment: Looking to your output of `str(m)` I noticed you have three data structures that are not exactly a conventional dataframe. Maybe that's the source of our problems. I would take a look at them more specifically and try to understand how they are different from the others. Maybe you should convert them to conventional dataframes with `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: when I type the number inside the `m[[ ]]` it shows me the correct data.frame, but when I put `m[[i]]` it shows me the names of the columns.

Comment: This `i` should give you an error. If it isn't giving you one that means it is defined as a variable and `i` has some value associated with it. Check which value is this. It is certainly referring to a specific dataframe among the ones in your list. I would say that it is probably the item 10 of your list `m`.

Comment: i isn't defined as a variable

Comment: and I don't think that the problem is with the 3 different data.frames because I tried everything  without them . I droped them

Comment: Doesn't make sense your `i` not being a variable and still when you type `m[[i]]` (outside of the `for` loop) it shows you the names of the columns.

Comment: my mistake, you right , Its shows me an error, that `i`doesn't exist, but Im still don't know what is the problem. I tried to add each column separately for example:  `X2016_kvish_1_10t$mean_values = mean_values[[1]]` but I must find a way to do it in one shot

Comment: All right, so how was that you were getting the column names in the steps above?

Comment: I mean, what did you do to obtain the result `[1] kvish keta maslul yom nefah status date` (when you said that you used `m[[i]]`)?

Comment: that because when I run that command you gave me `for(i in 1:length(m)){m[[i]]$means <- mean_values[[i]]} ' the i defined as `12` intiger. and then without noticing i did it again. my mistake

Comment: When you type `m[[12]]` it gives you the names of the columns? 'Cause if when `i` was set to `12` it gave you these, when you type `m[[12]]` you should obtain the same result. `m` being a list of data frames should return a dataframe regardless of what value you put inside the double square brackets...

Comment: Have you tried to rerun the code from the beggining? Make sure you start with the `m` list well defined.

Comment: When I type m[[12]] it gives me the 12's dataframe

Comment: When we do `for(i in 1:length(m))` were setting the `for` loop to iterate from 1 to `length(m)`. Each iteration is setting a new column `means` on the dataframe returned by `m[[i]]`. If all the dataframes are ok, then the only source of problem I can think of is `mean_values`. But I do not know how it is looking for you. And still we haven't found why you got column names before...

Comment: Ok, I opened a new post with this question. thanks anyway , you really helped me :)

Comment: Hey, I just noticed now that it worked well !!! but only when I call the whole list of dataframes . when I print each dataframe separately the new column doesn't appear

Comment: Nice that it worked. What do you mean when you say that the new column does not appear in the original dataframes? If you call any of them by using indexing like `m[[1]]` you should get the dataframes with the new columns...

Comment: When I print `m[[1]]` for example, it shows me the updated dataframe with the new column. but when I print the original `X2016_kvish_1_10t` the new column not there/ I need to find a way to apply the changes to the originals dataframes

Comment: I think I got you problem. The thing is... when you use the `for` loop expression I gave you we're messing only with the list `m`. If you have the original dataframes outside of the list as well, you won't get these specific dataframes to have the new column. Only the ones you have in the list `m`. However, it doesn't matter in the end, because to get the new columns in the original dataframes you would have to make them a list. Why do you want them outside of the list?

Comment: because I need to calculate and compute and to plot in each dataframe few things. and I need to compare between the dataframes

Comment: But you can do all this using the dataframes as items of the list.

Comment: Doing `rbind(X2016_kvish_1_10t, X2015_kvish_1_10t)` is exactly the same thing as doing `rbind(m[[1]], m[[2]])`.

Comment: I understand, but I stiil need to find a way to apply this changes in the originals dataframes

Comment: All right, please check my answer on your other post and see if that works for you.